# Ant Colony Optimisation Parameters

Tags: optimization, graphing-functions

To whom might be interested in helping me out,

I am working on a modified Ant Colony Optimisation algorithm. I feed the algorithm with five independent variables:  *AntCount*, *IterationCount*, *Beta*, *Alpha and the Number of Nodes*.
*AntCount* goes from 10 to 100. (In steps of 10). 
*IterationCount* goes from 10 to 100. (In steps of 10).
*Beta* goes from 1 to 10. (In steps of 1).
*Alpha* goes from 0.1 to 0.6 (In steps of 0.1).

An example of data set that I would get back from the algorithm looks like: 
[DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OREe.png)

My main idea is/was to plot all data at the same time to see which combination of parameters provides the best balance between performance and solution quality. However, I do not really know how to do that (graphically).

Besides plotting, which analysis would you perform on the data to support the graphs?.

Thanks for your time and consideration, it's highly appreciated!

P.S: I'm able to use SPSS or Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Do you know PCA? It doesn't graph everything but I can provide the best reduction to a number dimensions you can actually plot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ViktorGlombik. I don't know what PCA is... Plus, since I am a student I can't afford to buy another program.

Comment: PCA is a mathematical method not a computer program you can buy

Comment: Hey @ViktorGlombik, I have been reading about the Principal Component analysis method, but I do not see the connection with what am I asking. Could you please explain yourself further?

Comment: Have you read [this subsection of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Dimensionality_reduction)?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm working on understanding it. I also performed a Regression Analysis on my data, to compare it with the results I got when performing the Principal Component Analysis.